# URGENT linux who command show unknown IP address

Tags: ssh

when I issue `who` command I get the following output:

```
mehrdad  :2           2020-06-02 15:03 (:2)
mehrdad  pts/1        2020-06-02 15:48 (192.168.0.53)
```

I have no idea what/who is the IP address `192.168.0.53` and I myself have no ssh session currently, what does this means? is it a compromise situation?

Comment: Does that IP belong to your internal network? 
You can check if it logged in before with `last` command. Also `w` command can help you identifying the source

Comment: `arp -a | grep 192.168.0.53` might tell you the MAC of the device, then do a MAC lookup to see which hardware has the connection.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your current IP address, to know if the connection comes from inside:
`$ ip addr`

And try to understand the login from the logs:
`$ sudo cat /var/log/auth.log | grep mehrdad | tail`

If insecure, drop the connection:
`$ fuser -k /dev/pts/1`

If still insecure, close SSH:
`$ sudo service ssh stop`

You could check your firewall configurations, also.